# How to Create My Own Apk Package Installer?

Tags: android

Is there any way to create an apk package installer. Explaining a little I want to create it to install the apk in other directories of my application and to be able to execute them.

Comment: Yes. You will need to learn about the details of the APK format.

Comment: You could give me some advice or terms to help me orient myself to what is dear. Please. Thank you

Comment: You could google "apk format" and go from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are a community that enjoys helping others learn to program. You should take some time to browse our [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, check out the topics about [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). If you read this information, you will learn that your current question is much too broad for our current format. Any attempt to answer it will require the equivalent of a entire book on the topic. I suggest that you do some research yourself and learn more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Feel free to come back when you have very specific questions about details which you don't entirely understand.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have understood and accepted, I will adapt the correction given when asking my next question.